# How to get interface from object loaded from AssemblyLoadContext

Tags: c#, reflection, casting, dynamic-loading, assemblyloadcontext

```
/// <summary>
/// Here asm is loaded from HostAssemblyLoadContext 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="asm"></param>
/// <param name="alc"></param>
private void OptimizerAction(Assembly asm, HostAssemblyLoadContext alc)
{
    var types = asm.GetTypes().Where(type => type.GetInterface(nameof(IOptimizer)) != null).ToList();
    if (types.Count != 1)
    {
        return;
    }

    Type typeIOptimizer = types[0];
    MethodInfo? getInstance = typeIOptimizer.GetMethod("GetInstance", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
    if (getInstance != null)
    {
        object? obj = getInstance.Invoke(null, null);
        if (obj != null)
        {
            Debug.Assert(obj.GetType().Name == "Optimizer");
            var iopt = obj as IOptimizer;
            Debug.Assert(iopt != null); // ASSERTION FAIL *******

            if (obj is IOptimizer opt) // NEVER TRUE *******
            {
                opt.Optimize();   // HERE Never called. Thers is no IOptimizer found when loaded from AssemblyLoadContext
            }
        }
    }
```

Code loaded with AssemblyLoadContext give different behavior (than not using it):

In code, the assertion should be true. It is the case when not using AssemblyLoadContext.

```
     var iopt = obj as IOptimizer;
     Debug.Assert(iopt != null); // ASSERTION FAIL *******
```

In code, the next line should also be true. It is the case when not using AssemblyLoadContext.

```
  if (obj is IOptimizer opt) // NEVER TRUE *******
```

How to get the same behavior as when not using AssemblyLoadContext?

I know this question is the same as this: [AssemblyLoadContext, dynamically load an assembly, instantiate an object and cast to a shared interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58198370/assemblyloadcontext-dynamically-load-an-assembly-instantiate-an-object-and-cas). I know it seems to have different types (IOptimizer) seems to be 2 different types. But how to deal with that? Is there a way to be the same because they both comes from the same DLL? It should be the same.

Reference:

```
public class Optimizer : IOptimizer
{
    public static IOptimizer GetInstance() { return new Optimizer(); }
    ...
```

Code available at [GitHub - EricOuellet2/AssemblyLoadContext](https://github.com/EricOuellet2/AssemblyLoadContext)

Comment: Why don't you bounty the question you already know it's a dupe of, which is _already_ available?

Comment: Bounty are only available 48 hours after you asked the question. It will be a pleasure to do it because it actually blocks me to go further.

Comment: ...it's four and a half years old

Comment: But still does not have a valid answer for it????

Comment: Yes, I understand that. That's why I'm suggesting you **put a bounty on it**. Why knowingly ask the same thing again and wait 48 hours to bounty it?!

Comment: BECAUSE I CAN'T. I cannot bounty a question before 48 hours. Stack Overflow prevent user to do so. I would have done it, if I could have done it. Try it, you will see by yourself.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure if you're trolling; _"Member for 13 years, 7 months"_?! **Bounty [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58198370/assemblyloadcontext-dynamically-load-an-assembly-instantiate-an-object-and-cas).**

Comment: THANK YOU very much!!! I had no idea I could do that. Thanks a lot. I think my sample is more complete and a lot easier to test. I think I will improve my chances to get answer if I let it here, at least for the time to have appropriate answer(s). I give 100 for the moment but will give more in 1 day or 2. THANKS!!!!

Comment: You can also edit other people's posts, as long as you don't change the intent.

Comment: WOW!!! It is a little bit an intrusion... Do you think I can refer my sample to improve my chances peoples could try and see what I'm talking about???... I will do it (letting know peoples it is me not the author).

Comment: Duplicate of another question: [AssemblyLoadContext, dynamically load an assembly, instantiate an object and cast to a shared interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58198370/assemblyloadcontext-dynamically-load-an-assembly-instantiate-an-object-and-cas)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem. I found the solution in the Microsoft code sample at line 24 of this .cs file: [Github AssemblyLoadcontext Microsoft sample](https://github.com/dotnet/samples/blob/main/core/tutorials/Unloading/Host/Program.cs). (It is the same code which I started my sample but I haven't read everything).

I was referencing twice the same "OptimizerInterface.dll" where my interfaces were defined. One dll was in my main app folder and the other copy was in the folder where the dynamic loaded dll was. I removed the copy of "OptimizerInterface.dll" from the folder where the dynamic dll was loaded. BOOM -> Problem solved!!!

You can find the message (warning) in provided code in Github. You can also try the solution with the same code. Ref:  [Sample code to reproduce the error](https://github.com/EricOuellet2/AssemblyLoadContext)